# ARKit Plane Detection - Value of type 'ARView' has no member 'session'

Tags: ios, swift, augmented-reality, arkit, realitykit

I am trying to add plane detection to a simple ARKit app. I want to put a picture on a vertical plane.

So first I need to detect the plane then I can add my object anchor which I created in RealityKit.

However the problem is I am not sure the right method in detecting a plane and adding it to my scene with ARKit 3 and Xcode 11.

It should be as simple as:

```
import ARKit
import RealityKit

@IBOutlet var arView: ARView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let arConfiguration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
    arConfiguration.planeDetection = .horizontal
    arView.session.run(arConfiguration)
}
```

But I get the following error:

> Value of type 'ARView' has no member 'session'

I even tried the following which was used as an example by Apple from their WWDC demo (4:27),

[Apple Demo](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/605/)!

```
let anchor = AnchorEntity(plane: .verticle, minimumBounds: [0.2, 0.2])
arView.scene.addAnchor(anchor)
```

but I get the following error when trying to create an AnchorEntity

> Expression type 'AnchorEntity' is ambiguous without more context

```
import UIKit
import RealityKit
import ARKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var arView: ARView!

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        // Create a session configuration
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    func addFrame() {
        // Load the "Box" scene from the "Experience" Reality File
        let boxAnchor = try! Experience.loadBox()

        // Add the box anchor to the scene
        arView.scene.anchors.append(boxAnchor)
    }
}
```

Comment: In Xcode 13.2 there's no such issue anymore.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You get this error if your build destination is set to a Simulator. You need to select either an Actual Device or Generic iOS Device.

I've banged my head on this a couple of time and now add the following comment

```
    // If the following line fails to compile "Value of type 'ARView' has no member 'session'"
    // You need to select a Real Device or Generic iOS Device and not a simulator
    arView.session.run(configuration)
```

Comment: what if I have selected a real device and still get the error?

Comment: How are you creating your RealityKit ARView, in code or using a storyboard?

Comment: code. the error came up after I moved back from Xcode 12.3 to 12.2. Due to many freezing issues in version 12.3 I had to downgrade. Everything is working as expected, except that realitykit error.

Comment: Did you do a clean and rebuild of everything?

Comment: I cleaned the build folder if you mean that. when I am building the project everything is working as expected, but the canvas is always throwing errors in the scheme. Creating a new scheme and running that is fixing the issue neither.

Comment: I've had weird issues like this with previews. The one thing you can try is deleting the directories in DerivedData. To open your DerivedData directory do the following. Menu Xcode - Preferences... - Locations (Tab) - Derived Data section click the arrow.

Comment: that solved the issue. thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

If you use `iOS Simulator` for AR app based on *Interface Builder Storyboard*  or if you use `iOS SwiftUI Preview` – then you can't implement **session-oriented properties** and **anchoring components** for ARView. As you can see there are a lot of errors in this case.

### When Simulator is chosen in Xcode Active Scheme.

[image]

The only way to use **session-oriented properties** for your AR app is to choose a real iOS or iPadOS device in the **`Xcode Active Scheme`** drop-down menu.

### When real Apple device is chosen for build.

[image]

### The same is true for installGestures() method

iOS Simulator:

[image]

Real Device:

[image]

Comment: However it runs fine using ARSCNView, not sure what the issue is though

Comment: @JazKing, `ARSCNView` is symbiotic view based on two ingredients – ARKit and SceneKit, and as you said, it definitely runs fine. ARSession inside ARSCNView (that must be set by developer), ARFrames and ARAnchors here come from ARKit, models – from SceneKit. However, `ARView` is a view where session is automatically managed by RealityKit's app, and any anchor here can change the settings of session. The reason why it "can't run fine" in `ARView` lies in its nature – Xcode's Simulator doesn't support anchoring and doesn't support gestures for anchored models. RealityKit models must be anchored.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to eliminate this problem by using conditional compilation.

```
#if !targetEnvironment(simulator)
    return ARView(frame: .zero)
#else
    return UIView(frame: .zero)
#endif
```

The compilation issues stopped, but I will admit that I still have problems with previews. But I think that is more related to code complexity than to this error.

Answer (score 0):

Elaborating on the answer by Owen I can add that for me in SwiftUI the whole UIViewRepresentable struct became a compiler war zone! So many errors.
I found this way to fix it, maybe it can help others:

```swift
struct ARVideoPlayerContainer: UIViewRepresentable {
    // If I am on a real device execute my code
    #if !targetEnvironment(simulator)
    [...]
    #else
    // on the simulator execute a fake conformance to UIViewRepresentable... 
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView { UIView() }
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: Context) {}
    #endif
```